# Debugging Wordpress php template files with phpstorm crashes

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, themes

I am trying to debug a php template file with PhpStorm and it keeps crashing.

I am getting a exit signal Segmentation fault (11) from Apache Log.

- I can debug a plain .php file no problem
- When I try and put a breakpoint on a PHP call from within a file such as page.php with mixed HTML/PHP the debugger stumbles and the site crashes
- I have tried this on a basic WP 3.71 installation and on 3.6 on TwentyThirteen theme
- The debugger works fine on Drupal7 template files that are a mix of HTML/PHP

System:
- Mac 10.8
- MAMP

Fails on both Chrome and Firefox.

I have tried PhpStorm 6 & 7. I only get this problem debugging wordpress theme templates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No issues debugging on Lion with phpStorm 7 running WordPress 3.6.1.  I am not using Mamp though, I just have a straight Lamp stack on Mac using built in stuff. You might want to open an issue with JetBrains

Answer (score 1):

I worked out the problem thanks to a suggestion from JetBrains support. They suggested upgrading to 2.2.3 of xdebug.

So, I rebuilt xdebug to 2.2.3 (using pecl/perl) and I believe that this needed due to the new version of OS X Mavericks which I just upgraded to.

Thanks